# how to add .ray files to an opengl program?

Tags: c++, opengl, raytracing

I am using Microsoft visual studio 2012. I am trying to make a ray tracing program but I don't know how to include these .ray files into it. I heard you had to go to the projects tab, then go to properties, then to debugging, then to command arguments, then you would write the file name of the .ray file there. But my program isn't recognizing it. Can anyone help me out plz?

The file name of my .ray file is balls.ray

so in the command integuments I wrote $(balls)
and I made sure this file was in the same directory as my project

Answer (score 1):

The $()-Syntax is used for Macros in Visual Studio that are replaced by specific strings for each Project, and $(balls) is not one of them.

You have to add the **name** of your .ray file to the command line arguments, and then you need to read the file name from `argv`.

Without knowing what you try to do (or already tried), or at least showing your code, you won't get much help, though.